# intersection interface is valid in typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I know the difference between `type` and `interface`,
but what I'm confusing is that I can make `type` from `interface`.

For example

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

interface Props1 {
  age: number;
}

interface Props2 {
  name: string;
}

type Props = Props1 & Props2; // ====>>>> why is this possible ??

const App: React.FC<Props> = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I can not find any docs of it from the typescript handbook.
I want to know why this is possible.

Comment: Type aliases and interfaces are very similar, and in many cases you can choose between them freely. Almost all features of an interface are available in type, the key distinction is that a type cannot be re-opened to add new properties vs an interface which is always extendable. [see this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#differences-between-type-aliases-and-interfaces) hence interchangeable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intersection actually is not the same as extension. Even though these tools usually serve the same purpose.

I think [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) piece of TS documentation should be useful for you. Short quote from it:

> `interfaces` allowed us to build up new types from other types by extending them. TypeScript provides another construct called intersection types that is mainly used to combine existing object types.

Answer (score 1):

`Props1` and `Props2` are interfaces. an interface is a named `ObjectType`.

`Props1` and `Props2` as `ObjectType` are also `PrimaryType`. Indeed, a `PrimaryType` is defined as follows

```
PrimaryType:
ParenthesizedType
PredefinedType
TypeReference
ObjectType
ArrayType
TupleType
TypeQuery
ThisType
```

`PrimaryType` can be used as building blocks of `IntersectionType`. Indeed, the `IntersectionType` syntax is the following:

```
IntersectionType:
IntersectionOrPrimaryType & PrimaryType
```

So, `Props1 & Props2` is valid, since `Props1` and `Props2` are `PrimaryType` and results into an `IntersectionType`.

`Props` is a type alias, and the declaration syntax of type alias is the following:

```
TypeAliasDeclaration:
type BindingIdentifier TypeParametersopt = Type ;
```

As you can see, you only authorized to assign a `Type` to a type alias. in your example this means that `Props1 & Props2` needs to be a `Type` to be assignable.

What is a `Type` ?

A `Type` is defined as:

```
Type:
UnionOrIntersectionOrPrimaryType
FunctionType
ConstructorType
```

Since `Props1 & Props2` is an `IntersectionType`, this means it is also a `Type`, and so assignable to `Props`